# Emoji viewing on Android 5.1

Tags: emoticons

I've seen a number of similar questions, but none have worked for me.
A friend keeps sending me emojis, and 99% of the time, it's perfect and I see what I want.  However, the other 1% I can't see them.  I would like to know a specific one, but I am getting the little box.  I've tried copy and pasting it into a browser, etc. and it still does the same thing.  Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [Emojisearch](http://emojisearch.com/).

It displays image of searched emoji so if particular emoji is not supported for your mobile you can still see it.

[FAQs on Emoji](http://www.unicode.org/faq/emoji_dingbats.html)